# db2 python [PROCESSING FAILURE]

Tags: python-3.x, db2

I am very new to db2.I am trying to connect to db2 using python but getting below error.

> SQLCODE=-30082][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed
>   with reason "15" ("PROCESSING FAILURE").  SQLSTATE=08001

I have simple python code for this.

```
import ibm_db
db =ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=mysample;HOSTNAME=localhost;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=db2admin; PWD=Password01;", "", "")


if db:
    print ("success")
```

on the internet, I got below link [SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "15"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417500)

I have installed db2 community C edition on windows 7 professional. I can connect to the db2 mysample database using SQL workbench . not sure what the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to operating system file and permission access to the user I was trying to access in my windows 7. I reinstalled db2 express C edition with unchecking enable operating system security check option during the installation screenshot [image: db2 installation]